# Python: How to convert Pyspark column to date type if there are null values

Tags: python, date, apache-spark, null, pyspark

In pyspark, I have a dataframe that has dates that get imported as strings.  There are null values in these dates-as-strings columns.  I'm trying to convert these columns into date type columns, but I keep getting errors.  Here's a small example of the dataframe:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|DeviceId|   Created| EventDate|
+--------+----------+----------+
|       1|      null|2017-03-09|
|       1|      null|2017-03-09|
|       1|2017-03-09|2017-03-09|
|       1|2017-03-15|2017-03-15|
|       1|      null|2017-05-06|
|       1|2017-05-06|2017-05-06|
|       1|      null|      null|
+--------+----------+----------+
```

When there are no null values, I have found that this code below will work to convert the data types:

```
dt_func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'), DateType())    
df = df.withColumn('Created', dt_func(col('Created')))
```

Once I add null values it crashes.  I've tried to modify the udf to account for nulls as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def convertDatetime(x):
    return sf.when(x.isNull(), 'null').otherwise(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
dt_func =  udf(convertDatetime, DateType())
```

I also tried filling the nulls with an arbitrary date-string, converting the columns to dates, and then trying to replace the arbitrary fill date with nulls as below:

```
def dt_conv(df, cols, form = '%Y-%m-%d', temp_plug = '1900-01-01'):
    df = df.na.fill(temp_plug)
    dt_func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, form), DateType())

    for col_ in cols:
        df = df.withColumn(col_, dt_func(col(col_)))
    df = df.replace(datetime.strptime(temp_plug, form), 'null')
    return df
```

However, this method gives me this error

```
ValueError: to_replace should be a float, int, long, string, list, tuple, or dict
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this -

```
# Some data, I added empty strings and nulls both
data = [(1,'','2017-03-09'),(1,None,'2017-03-09'),(1,'2017-03-09','2017-03-09')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF('id','Created','EventDate')
df.show()
```

:

```
+---+----------+----------+
| id|   Created| EventDate|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|          |2017-03-09|
|  1|      null|2017-03-09|
|  1|2017-03-09|2017-03-09|
+---+----------+----------+
```

:

```
df\
.withColumn('Created-formatted',when((df.Created.isNull() | (df.Created == '')) ,'0')\
.otherwise(unix_timestamp(df.Created,'yyyy-MM-dd')))\
.withColumn('EventDate-formatted',when((df.EventDate.isNull() | (df.EventDate == '')) ,'0')\
.otherwise(unix_timestamp(df.EventDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')))\
.drop('Created','EventDate')\
.show()
```

:

```
+---+-----------------+-------------------+
| id|Created-formatted|EventDate-formatted|
+---+-----------------+-------------------+
|  1|                0|         1489035600|
|  1|                0|         1489035600|
|  1|       1489035600|         1489035600|
+---+-----------------+-------------------+
```

I used `unix_timestamp` which returns BigInt format but you can format that columns as you like .

Comment: What do I need to import for unix_timestamp?  I get `NameError: name 'unix_timestamp' is not defined`

Comment: The proposed solution fills the `null` and `''` values with `0`'s.  Is there a way to convert the type without filling with `0`?

Comment: You can fill it with anything you want. something like which you have tried --to put some arbitrary date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... just casting the column!

```
df_new = (df
            .select(to_date(col("df.EventDate"),"yyyy-MM-dd")
            .alias("EventDate-formatted")
         )
```